# Chessbase 16 - Sort variations

Tags: software, chessbase

Is there a way to sort variations in Chessbase 16?
For example, if I add two variations and then I want to move the second variation up in the list, without promoting it to main line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're at the point where there are the variations, click the right arrow key as you normally would to click through moves. Then, the "Variations" dialog box should pop up. At this point, use the up or down arrow key to navigate to the move you want to sort. Then, click on the "Move up" or "Move down" button.